# "Fidget Cube" українською

Tags: from-english

Доброго дня!
Сьогодні популярною є іграшка "Fidget Cube", однак як правильно називати її українською? Транслітерувати як "фіджет куб" (такий варіант я знайшов на сайті UpTrends) чи як "фиджет куб" (цей варіант із сайту Розетка)? Чи все ж можливо є якийсь український відповідник? І хоч Fidget Cube Гугл перекладач не може адекватно перекласти, однак Fidget він перекладає як "метушня". Тому можливо варіант кубік-антистрес буде вірний?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Відповідно до [§ 90 «Правопису»](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil3.htm#par90) (так зване «[правило дев'ятки](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B2'%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8)» у таких випадках звук зазвичай передається літерою *і* — ***фіджет***. Фактично всі фрагменти правопису, що мають стосунок до цього випадку, зацитував [m0rpheus](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/u/1556) у тексті [цього запитання](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/4000) (тільки там приголосним, що передує, був *к*, а тут приголосним, що передує, є *ф* — але правила щодо передачі іноземного *i/и* після цих приголосних не відрізняються).

Українські відповідники мені невідомі. Фіджет-куб і [фіджет-спінер](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80), як я розумію, ворушать чи вертять у руках для заспокоєння. [Андрусишин і Крет як один із відповідників дієслова  *fidget* пропонують *го́мзатися*](//e2u.org.ua/s?w=fidget&dicts=8&highlight=on). Відповідно, можна спробувати вигадати щось на зразок *го́мзалки* (***го́мзалка***, що її *го́мза́ють* ([1](http://hrinchenko.com/slovar/znachenie-slova/9927-ghomzatysja.html#show_point), [2](//books.google.com/books?id=EWPorsyvlQMC&pg=PA276&dq=%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8), [3](http://hramnagorke.ru/gloss/33/764/)) у руках для заспокоєння). Це підійшло би як узагальнюючий термін і для фіджет-куба і для фіджет-спінера, але для останнього є інші неологізми. Це, звісно, жодним чином не нормативний термін, лише моя спроба на ходу щось вигадати.

Comment: Є ще слово fidgety (прийменник до fidget) що також має багато перекладів на українську: https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=fidgety&dicts=all&highlight=on&filter_lines=on.

Comment: @Yola, я не проти.

Comment: @Artemix, _ворушни́к_? _кни́пка_? _шве́ндик_?

Comment: А може крутькО-куб?